# How do you move into a next page using props in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My current code is

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'native-base';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class All extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress=>{ this.props.navigation.navigate('SellHowto') }>
        <Text>submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

**AuthenticationNavigator.js**

```js
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import TabNavigator from 'app/src/navigations/TabNavigator';
import LoadingScreen from 'app/src/screens/authentication/Loading';
import SellHowtoScreen from 'app/src/screens/sell/Howto';

const AuthenticationNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Loading: { screen: LoadingScreen },
      SellHowto: { screen: SellHowtoScreen },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Loading',
    },
  ),
);

export default AuthenticationNavigator;
```

**TabNavigator.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import HomeScreen from 'app/src/screens/home/Index';
import SellScreen from 'app/src/screens/sell/Index';

const BottomTabNavigatorConfig = {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  tabBarOptions: { showLabel: true },
};
const TabNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'Home',
        },
      },
      Sell: {
        screen: SellScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'Sell',
        },
      },
    },
    BottomTabNavigatorConfig,
  ),
);

export default TabNavigator;
```

**sell/Index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import ScrollableTabView from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
import All from 'app/src/screens/sell/All';

export default class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollableTabView style={{ marginTop: 30, flex: 1 }}>
        <All tabLabel="all"/>
      </ScrollableTabView>
    );
  }
}
```

**sell/All.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'native-base';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class All extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress=>{ this.props.navigation.navigate('SellHowto') }>
        <Text>submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I can't go to SellHowto page from sell/All.js.
Also, I got two more pages after SellHowto page.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to keep state in next page by giving props.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to navigate from a component that is a direct descendant of a router that you have the navigation prop available and you can use `this.props.navigation.navigate(<route>)` to navigate.
If the component is not a direct descendant of a router you can wrap it inside the withNavigation hoc provided by react-navigation and it will drill the navigation prop to you component and then again you can use it in the same way mentioned above

Comment: Thank you for advising! How can I wrap the component that is a not direct descendent of a router inside the withNavigation hoc?

Comment: Also you can pass threw params while navigating by writing: , {paramname: paramvalue} after the routename.

Comment: if you are using react-navigation v <= 4 then you can import withNavigation from react-navigation and then when exporting your component 
export withNavigation(<YourComponent>). in higher versions withNavigation will be part of a compatibility package: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/compatibility